# don't work pyuic or other ways of converting from ui to py

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I Installed Qt Creator, made a form, now there is a project in which, as I understand it is necessary to make somehow from ui format py. Tried through pyuic, but not an option as it is not elementary installed through pip.

[image]

At first I thought that I had a pip working incorrectly, but with a peep, like everything is fin

[image]

Are there other ways to convert ui to py, or can anyone know how to fix this error? I'm working on mac.

Comment: The package that contains pyuic5 is called `pyqt5-tools`

Comment: You can use the [uic module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#the-uic-module).